# Do old chat messages get deleted?

Tags: support

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/87765/166373

I'm trying to look at the discussions that were moved to chat but it gives me a "Page Not Found" error.  Is it because it was too old?

Answer (score 2):

Chatrooms for comments get auto-deleted after a week of inactivity. This fits with the ephemeral nature of comments on the whole.

Comment: I've never actually watched a custom chat room long term before, but is the chat room created from comments treated differently than a normal chat room? For a normal chat room, if the room has no active chatters and fewer than 15 messages by 2 users, it is deleted after 7 days. If the room has no active chatters and more than 15 messages by 2 users, the room is frozen. [From the chat FAQ.](http://chat.stackexchange.com/faq#retention).

Answer (score 1):

I can still see [the chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34522/discussion-on-answer-by-jarrod-roberson-how-to-convince-my-boss-that-quality-is) (this may possibly be a function of reputation). Anyway, here it is. Click to embiggen.

[image: Screenshot of chat window]

The only thing missing off the bottom of the screen is the "This chat room has been deleted for inactivity" message.